# how write in phpspreadsheet cell by using loop

Tags: php, loops, phpspreadsheet

I would like to make phpspreadsheet  like [image]
I've tried below code

```
   foreach( range('A','C') as $ro) { 
        $r= $ro . "4";    
    $sheet->setCellValue($r,'Sn');
    $sheet->setCellValue($r,'Name');
    $sheet->setCellValue($r,'Title');
    }
```

but it shows as [image]

So, How can get my desired excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't just do it without a loop?

```
$sheet->setCellValue('A4','Sn');
$sheet->setCellValue('B4','Name');
$sheet->setCellValue('C4','Title');
```

The problem is that for every iteration in your foreach loop, you are replacing the value of the same cell.

In first iteration, we will have `$r = 'A4'`. Then you set A4 to "Sn". After that you set A4 to "Name" and then you set A4 to "Title". By then, you've replaced the content of the same cell 3 times for this iteration.

So it's best to skip the loop.

If you insist on looping, you could introduce logic that maps specific columns to specific values, but unless you have other specific logic involved, it is really overcomplicating the solution

---

If you want to loop because of many column names, I suggest you loop over an array of columns. If you use a normal array it will be zero-indexed, which means you can map it to the appropriate character with the `chr()` function by adding 65 to the index. Note that this will only work for 26 columns or less.

```php
$columns = ['Sn', 'Name', 'Title'];

foreach ($columns as $index => $column) {
  $cell = chr($index + 65) . "4";

  $sheet->setCellValue($cell, $column);
}
```

You can also use an associative array and have the column be the key of the array - this would work for any amount of columns (but you still have to define the map)

```php
$columns = [
  'A' => 'Sn',
  'B' => 'Name',
  'C' => 'Title'
];

foreach ($columns as $index => $column) {
  $sheet->setCellValue($index."4", $column);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Actually I can do it manually but I have 60 column, so that I've tried by loop. If I do it manually (A4,B4, C4....)and if need to change, then it is very difficult to change every column address. So is there are any way ?

Comment: @OhidulIslam I've updated my answer to include an example. Hope it helps